# How to get initialValue from redux-fom with dynamic named form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I would like to explain what i have done so far

1. I have created dynamic form with form parameter as below

   ```
   <PrintingForm
       img={img}
       form={img.id}
       onChangeHandler={this.handlePrintFrame}
   />
   ```

   This have created the form with that dynamic id filed
2. following is the code for the PrintingForm Component

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { connect } from 'react-redux';
   import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
   import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

   const renderTextField = ({
     input,
     label,
     meta: { touched, error },
     ...custom
   }) => (
     <TextField
       label={label}
       type="number"
       InputLabelProps={{
         shrink: true,
       }}
       margin="normal"
       variant="outlined"
       errorText={touched && error}
       {...input}
       {...custom}
     />
   );
   class PrintingForm extends Component {
     onChangeHandler = (event, img) => {
       this.props.onChangeHandler(
         img.id,
         img.actualFile,
         img.imgUrl,
         'p4by6',
         event
       );
     };
     render() {
       const {
         img,
         initialValues,
       } = this.props;

       return (
         <form>
           <Field
             name="p4by6"
             component={renderTextField}
             label="4*6"
             img={img}
             onChange={e => this.onChangeHandler(e, img)}
           />
         </form>
       );
     }
   }
   PrintingForm = reduxForm({})(PrintingForm);
   PrintingForm = connect(state => ({
     initialValues: state.form,
   }))(PrintingForm);

   export default PrintingForm;
   ```

Its working fine for onChange onBlur and other events of redux-form. Now I want to get the initial values to be **rendered** while navigating this component afterwards.

Comment: If i have added the enableReinitialize: true, in the reduxForm() Hoc then the whole component cant be loaded ............

Answer (score 0):

I did not get what exactly you need, but I guess the following could be helpful:

in the component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    primaryName: state.form.userBlockForm.values.primaryName,
    secondaryName: state.form.userBlockForm.values.secondaryName,
    blockColor: state.form.userBlockForm.values.blockColor
  }
}

export default reduxForm(
  {
    form: 'userBlockForm',
    initialValues: {
      primaryName: '',
      secondaryName: '',
      blockColor: '#FFBC0A',
    },
    enableReinitialize: true,
    keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true,
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true
  }
)(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    handleUserBlockDialogClose,
    handleUserBlockCreate
  }
)(UserBlockDialog));
```

Use redux middleware:

```
const reduxFormMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  console.log('redux-form-middleware');
  const actionType = action.type.split('/');
  if (actionType[0] === '@@redux-form') {
    switch(actionType[1]) {
      case 'INITIALIZE': {
        switch(action.meta.form) {
          case 'userBlockForm': {
            const block = store.getState().controls.userBlockSavingAs;
            if (block) {
              action.meta.keepDirty = false;
              action.payload = {
                primaryName: block.primaryName,
                secondaryName: block.secondaryName,
                blockColor: block.color
              }
            } else {
              const values = store.getState().form.userBlockForm.values;
              if (values) {
                action.payload = {
                  primaryName: values.primaryName,
                  secondaryName: values.secondaryName,
                  blockColor: values.blockColor
                }
              }
            }
            next(action);
            break;           
          }
          case 'arrayForm': {
            next(action);
            break;
          }

          default:
            next(action);
        }
      }

      default:
        next(action);
    }
  }
  next(action);
}

export default reduxFormMiddleware;
```